# Vue3 Pinia Store cannot access 'store" before initializsation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, pinia

I have a UserStore which contains some information about the current user. This store also is responsible for loggin in and out.

In order to make the getters available I map the getters to my computed attribute within my Vue component.

Unfortunately I get an error saying that it cannot access useUserStore before initilization.

This is my component:

```
<template>
  //...
</template>

<script>
import {mapState} from "pinia"
import {useUserStore} from "../../stores/UserStore.js";
import LoginForm from "../../components/forms/LoginForm.vue";

export default {
  name: "Login",
  components: {LoginForm},
  computed: {
    ...mapState(useUserStore, ["user", "isAuthenticated"]) //commenting this out makes it work
  }
}
</script>
```

This is my store:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import {gameApi} from "../plugins/gameApi.js"
import {router} from "../router.js";

export const useUserStore = defineStore("UserStore", {
    persist: true,
    state: () => ({
            authenticated: false,
            _user: null
    }),

    getters: {
        user: (state) => state._user,
        isAuthenticated: (state) => state.authenticated
    },

    actions: {
        async checkLoginState() {
            // ...
        },
        async loginUser(fields) {
            // ...
        },
        async logutUser() {
            // ...
        }
    }
})
```

And my main.js

```
import {createApp} from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import gameApi from './plugins/gameApi'
import {router} from './router.js'
import store from "./stores/index.js";

createApp(App)
    .use(store)
    .use(router)
    .use(gameApi)
    .mount('#app')
```

And finally my store configuration:

```
import {createPinia} from "pinia"
import piniaPluginPersistedstate from 'pinia-plugin-persistedstate'
import {useUserStore} from "./UserStore.js";

const piniaStore = createPinia()
piniaStore.use(piniaPluginPersistedstate)

export default {
    install: (app, options) => {
        app.use(piniaStore)

        const userStore = useUserStore()
        const gameStore = useGameStore()
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is likely with dependency graph. Try to move `import App` lower. Check if the use of `import LoginForm` affects this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to initialize the store using the "old" way comparable with Vuex. Instead I had to make use of the `setup()` function [Pinia Docu](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/actions.html#with-setup):

```
<script>
import {useUserStore} from "../../stores/UserStore.js";

export default {
  name: "RegisterForm",

  setup() {
    // initialize the store
    const userStore = useUserStore()
    return {userStore}
  },

  data() {
    return {
      // ...
    }
  },

  methods: {
    checkLoginState() {
      this.userStore.checkLoginState()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: There is an open issue to fix this problem https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/3033. Some people managed to solve it by adding additional configuration in vite.config.ts plugins. With me it didn't work. Unfortunately I will be using your solution

Comment: This is definitely a problem with vite. My code with webpack works. What I suggest for some people is to use a vite version below 4.0.13